# Xamarin Android SSL Authentication failed

Tags: android, ssl, xamarin, https

I have a Xamarin Android app connecting to a dot net core WebAPI running on an Ubuntu box.

I can connect to the api, however when I try displaying an Image or connecting to SignalR, I am getting an SSL error:

System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception. ---> Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsException: Ssl error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Any ideas how to investigate or resolve this? I can access the Image and website from the browser (Mac, Windows, Android browser) and it works on Xamarin iOS but just not on Android.

EDIT: I've just checked in PostMan when calling the URL of the domain and getting this error

> SSL Error: Certificate has expired

I have checked using Chrome and Firefox, the Certificate looks to be valid:

Not Before: 01 Sep 2021
Not After: 30 Nov 2021

Issuer is Let's Encrypt.

I have also checked using a couple of online SSL checkers including my hosts one and both have said the certificate is valid - so I am really not sure what the next steps are here..

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69397845/trust-issue-while-sending-a-post-to-my-api-since-dst-root-ca-x3-expiration

Comment: Thanks - i ended up just buying a certificate from a different organisation in the end